# How to get url parameters added to url of appstore application from within the app installed using that url in objective c, xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, url

To clarify, if I add an url parameter `transaction_id` to a standard app store application url, i.e.

```
itunes.apple.com/us/app/rollball/id417598423?mt=8
```

so its url looks like this:

```
itunes.apple.com/us/app/rollball/id417598423?mt=8&transaction_id=999888777
```

how do I "read" that parameter when user installs app using given link.

So, I would like to be able to access `transaction_id` from the code. I guess there is some callback method that can provide dictionary containing all url parameters added to itunes app link, but after hours and hours of research, I couldn't find any.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, you have access to this parameter or the url alltogether. As is understood, you have an URL from which the user will be directed to the App at the iTunes store or where he is able to install  an enterprise signed app?

The only way i know to access external data is via URL schemes with a custom protocol (http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html)

Please clarify your question, perhaps there is an answer :)

Comment: I have an URL that points to app in apple appstore. URL has extra parameter. I need to read that parameter from the app so I could return value to the download campaign tracking system.

Comment: first of all i don't think that the url will be passed to your app by the iTunes store after you the user installed your app from the store. and beside that - the user installs the app through the "install" or "buy" button within the store and then the app will be installed on the device. this process is done by the OS and you have no possibility to intervene.

perhaps google analytics SDK offers something for you? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/campaigns